# Performance improvement of FilteredTree

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, treeviewer

I'm using FilteredTree class to filter over my TreeViewer contents, but as there is lots of data now, when I type in something to filter the data, it hangs before I enter my next letter. Is there any way that I can improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to mitigate a slow filter would be to increase the delay between running the filter. This allows users to type multiple characters before the filter is re-run.

In your subclass of FilteredTree, override getRefreshJobDelay(). The default is 200 ms, perhaps allowing 500-800ms is more appropriate for your use case?

For example consider the use case in [Eclipse PDE of a filtered tree](https://git.eclipse.org/c/pde/eclipse.pde.ui.git/tree/ui/org.eclipse.pde.ui/src/org/eclipse/pde/internal/ui/editor/plugin/ExtensionsSection.java#n1472):

```
@Override
protected long getRefreshJobDelay() {
    // Prolonged job delay time is required because of the attribute search being more costly in nature.
    // This can block input to the filter text severely. Thus it shouldn't happen when typing slowly.
    // The delay of 1500ms is bypassed by some actions that use the filter text to initiate searches or clear the text.
    long delay = (fBypassFilterDelay) ? 0 : REFRESHJOB_DELAY_TIME;
    setBypassFilterDelay(false); // reset afterwards
    return delay;
}
```

Where REFRESHJOB_DELAY_TIME is 1200ms.

If you are looking to speed up your filter implementation perhaps posting it would help?